# Using a 3rd party JDBC driver with Coldfusion?

Tags: jdbc, coldfusion

I'm attempting to use a 3rd party JDBC driver with my Coldfusion installation, but I've gone wrong somewhere, and I'm not exactly certain where.

I placed the .jar file inside of cfusion\wwwroot as well as WEB-INF\lib, but did not add it to my Datasources, as I'm not exactly certain if I have to/how I would since it is a local file.

Then, inside my test.cfm file I added the following code:

```
<cfset objDriver = createObject("java","java.sql.DriverManager")>
<cfset prop = createObject("java","java.util.Properties").init()>

<cfset prop.put("prop1", "prop1")>
<cfset prop.put("prop2", "prop2")>
<cfset prop.put("prop3", "prop3")>

<cfset conn = objDriver.getConnection("jdbc:mydriver:", prop) >
```

I verified that the properties and connection work fine in Java, so this is not the issue persay, but when I go to the page I get the following error on getConnection():

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mydriver:
```

I was wondering if I missed something obvious or silly.

Comment: Don't do all that. Add a datasource and use cfquery/cfstoredproc.

Comment: [This page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3639b1-7fe6.html) says there's a chapter about it in "Configuring and Administering ColdFusion"...

Comment: Thanks, not certain why I wanted to use Java...been a bit since I had done any ColdFusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would add it to the datasources instead. Otherwise you are going to end up writing ugly Java code to "get around" the driver.

To add to the DSN's use the "other" datasource and add a "connection string". These are specifica to the driver and you should have some samples associated with the driver you have downloaded. They serve as a good starting point.

You can see strings from other datasources you have added by examining the "neo-datasources.xml" file in the /lib directory of your CF install.

You will need to insure the driver is in the /lib directory of the CF install (not the same as WEB-INF/Lib) on older version of CF - not sure about CF 10.  You also need to restart CF after putting it in the directory.

alternately you can add the file to the classpath by editing the jvm config file.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it all set up, now I just need to get the connection to work, for some reason I can't get my properties to work as a connection string (1 is user and 1 is password, which work with the standard properties, but the 3rd is an AccessKey that doesn't seem to want to take). As far as the directory 10 seems to be happy with WEB-INF/Lib

Comment: Connection strings vary by driver. What driver are you using? Does it have a public API?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using an internal one that doesn't really have a public API, but I got it working in Java with the following code:

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    
    prop.put("AccessToken", "accesstoken");
    prop.put("User", "user");
    prop.put("Password", "password");
      
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mydriver:", prop); 

But I'm uncertain what I'm doing wrong trying to add the AccessKey...

Comment: You need to translate it into a jdbc connection URL. What does your CF DSN "connection string" look like? I am guessing something like this? `jdbc:mydriver://dbName;User=username;Password=password;AccessToken=accessToken` Your driver should have an example...

Comment: Actually I am using the proper connection URL, and I do have an example of it, but for some reason my page may not be using it?

`jdbc:mydriver:User=username;Password=password;Access Token=accessToken;`

Though I was missing the space for the access token, my page still gives me "Login failed: You must provide a user and password to login."

Comment: Well like I said, the "magic connection url" string all depends on the driver. So without seeing an example or documentation, that is my best shot ;)

Comment: Haha, that code block was copied and pasted out of the driver's documentation unfortunately. I think my problem lies in actually USING the connection string for my connection though, because I can put whatever I want in that box, and CF doesn't seem to care...

Comment: Does the example connection string to work in java (directly) ? ie Not using `java.util.Properties` or CF at all. Because the url looks odd. Typically a connection url includes a database name. I do not see one in your example ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14490/discussion-between-doyler-and-leigh)